# Having trouble using SpeedTracer for Google Chrome

Tags: html, performance

I am trying to find the bottle neck in [this](http://nanisolutions.us/wordpress/) site here. Granted, there is not much on the page now, but I will be uploading nearly 300 images to this site in the coming week which I expect to take a toll on speed and performance. Therefore, I want to cut down on everything other than image loading as much as possible.

I've attached an image which shows what I'm seeing in SpeedTracer, but the data makes no sense to me. The page loaded in around 4 seconds, yet each of these blue bars is claiming to have taken ~ 3.5 seconds to load. How can this be?

Could someone try to provide me with some explanation as to what I'm looking at here?

[image: My View]

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a waterfall of the page and it's resources loading...

Each row represents an individual resource, and show's when it started loading and how long it  took.

Browsers can download resources in parallel - Chrome can download up to six resources from the same hostname e.g. www.nanisolutions.com, at the same time. It can also download up to six resources from every other hostname at the same time (up to maximum of 40 connections)

Quite why you screen grab shows the request for the root HTML document starting after some of the items I'm not sure but I'm wondering if you are on the same network as the webserver?

I'd be tempted to run the same test using webpagetest.org

Comment: Would it make any difference that I'm using shared hosting?